# Ravi Vakil Easy Exercise 1.3.X Sanity Check

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

I was reading through the existence of fiber products in the category of schemes from Ravi Vakil's notes and chased a reference in one of the steps to two exercises from chapter 1:

> **1.3.R** Exercise. Given morphisms $X_1 \to Y$, $X_2 \to Y$, and $Y \to Z$, show that there is a natural morphism $X_1 \times_Y X_2 \to X_1 \times_Z X_2$, assuming that both fibered products exist. (This is trivial once you figure out what it is saying. The point of this exercise is to see why it is trivial.)

> **1.3.X** Easy Exercise. We use the notation of Exercise 1.3.R.  Show that if $Y \to Z$ is a monomorphism, then the morphism $X_1 \times_Y X_2 \to X_1 \times_Z X_2$ you described in Exercise 1.3.R is an isomorphism. (Hint: for any object $V$, give a natural bijection between maps from $V$ to the first and maps from $V$ to the second.  It is also possible to use the Diagonal-Base-Change diagram, Exercise 1.3.S.)

Am I nuts, or are these both false without the added assumption that in the cartesian diagrams
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X_1 \times_Y X_2 @>p_2>> X_2\\
@V p_1 V V @VV f_2 V\\
X_1 @>>f_1> Y
\end{CD}
and
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X_1 \times_Y X_2 @>q_2>> X_2\\
@V q_1 V V @VV g_2 V\\
X_1 @>>g_1> Z
\end{CD}
$g_2 \circ p_2 = g_1 \circ p_1$?

For example, I'm pretty sure the following setup yields a counter-example to 1.3.X: the sets $X_1 = \{1\}$, $X_2 = \{2\}$, $Y = \{1,2\}$, and $Z = \{1,2,3\}$ equipped with the morphisms $f_1(1) = 1$ $f_2(2) = 2$; $g_1(1) = 3$, $g_2(2) = 3$, and the inclusion $Y \subset Z$ produce the non-isomorphic fiber products $$X_1 \times_Y X_2 = \left\{(a,b) \in X_1 \times X_2 : f_1(a) = f_2(b)\right\} = \emptyset$$
and
$$X_1 \times_Z X_2 = \left\{(a,b) \in X_1 \times X_2 : g_1(a) = g_2(b)\right\} = X_1 \times X_2 \neq \emptyset$$

Comment: No, these are both true (without any more assumptions) and what you're missing is that the morphism from each X_i to Z is canonical: given by the composition X_i -->Y --> Z. So your counterexample isn't really one for the same reason, as you have rigged the g's.

Comment: I'm not sure I buy this.  The fiber products are taken in an arbitrary category, so the morphisms to $Y$ or to $Z$ are integral to the formation of the product and, unlike a slice category, the objects $X_i$ are not changed just because the object over which they live has changed.  If anything, I would expect the correct hypothesis to be a morphism between the diagrams $X_1 \rightarrow Y \leftarrow X_2$ and $X_1 \rightarrow Z \leftarrow X_2$.

Comment: See the answer by KReiser which is the same thing I’ve said. You’re overthinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maps involved in the definition of the fiber product $X_1\times_Z X_2$ in the statements made by Vakil are intended to be the composition of morphisms $X_i\to Y$ and $Y\to Z$. This immediately gives the additional condition on the $g_i$ and $p_i$ you've specified in your post.

(FWIW, I've never before seen anyone attempt to break this sort of thing the way you're trying to.)

Comment: I certainly agree as you and Cranium Clamp point out that if we assume the $X_i$ are objects over $Y$ and $Z$ and those structures are compatible, then the result is trivial. However, I was more concerned that the compatibility is explicitly not implied the hypotheses.  Basically, I started to worry that the usual definition of fiber product (e.g., concisely, $X_1 \times_Y X_2$ is the product of $X_1 \to Y$ and $X_2 \to Y$ in $\mathcal{C} \downarrow Y$) and the thing being called a fiber product in the AG context were not actually the same.

Comment: Could the fiber products be a little better specified? Sure. I think that this is essentially the only reasonable thing to do from the information provided, though: you need maps $X_i \to Z$, and you have maps $X_i \to Y$ and $Y\to Z$, so compose them. Worry not: the fiber product in algebraic geometry is the same fiber product as everywhere else.

Comment: Oh, that's it.  Now I see how I was being dumb.  I misread the statement as given fiber products $X_1 \times_Y X_2$  and $X_1 \times_Z X_2$, and a mono $Y \to Z$, there is a canonical isomorphism between the fiber products.  The intent is given the fiber product $X_1 \times_Y X_2$ and a mono $Y \to Z$, then we can form $X_1 \times_Z X_2$ *and* it's isomorphic to $X_1 \times_Y X_2$.  Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's the intent. You're welcome.